# Histogram not being plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
data = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2]
print("mean : ",np.mean(data))
print("Standard deviation : ",np.std(data))
print("max : ",np.max(data))
print("min : ",np.min(data))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.interactive(True)

plt.show(data)
```

This is my code for drawing a histogram in pycharm but it ain't showing anything , just printing the print statement. Need help !

Comment: paste full code

Comment: I think that's the full code

Comment: You're not plotting anything here... which is probably why nothing is showing!

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque This is my full code , apart from this code are the libraries . Just wanted to check the histogram being plotted or not so the code is quite simple

Comment: `import inline as inline
import matplotlib
import unicodecsv
import matplotlib as plt
import numpy as np` 
These are the libraries

Comment: @ZainAfzal. I gave your problem's answer in the answer section. :)

Answer (score 3):

You must plot the histogram, here is how:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots, show

data = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2]

fig, ax = subplots()
ax.hist(data)

show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a plot first with `plt.plot(data)` and then show it with  `plt.show()`. To plot the histogram, you call `plt.hist(data)` before `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually tell matplotlib what you want to plot - in this case, the histogram of `data`.

```
data = [1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2]
print("mean : ",np.mean(data))
print("Standard deviation : ",np.std(data))
print("max : ",np.max(data))
print("min : ",np.min(data))
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.interactive(True)
plt.hist(data)
plt.show(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `plt.interactive(True)` instesd of this you can use `plt.interactive(False)`.Then You can run you code and you will show `graph` :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import asarray

data = asarray([1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2])

print("mean : ", data.mean())
print("Standard deviation : ", data.std())
print("max : ", data.max())
print("min : ", data.min())

# plt.interactive(True)
plt.interactive(False)

plt.plot(data)
plt.show()

#plot histogram
plt.hist(data)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You've made a fairly simple concept quite complicated, don't you think? I mean, importing 5 packages is not really necessary.

Comment: I know @Pouria . Questioner has imported these pakages (comment section). I just find out his mistake from editing his question.

Comment: I thought it might have been a mistake given your reputations. I edited your response anyway.